# How to convert the value in big number in solidity using truffle framework?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I am having this error while testing my contract. All of the tests are passing except the last one. I don't understand this error, please help.
the smart contract is created with truffle framework.

my lottery-contract sol file:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
      pragma solidity >= 0.5.2;
      contract Lottery{
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;
    constructor()public{
        manager=msg.sender;
        
    }
    function enter() public payable{
        require(msg.value>0.01 ether);
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }
    function random() private view returns(uint){
      return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty,block.timestamp,players)));
    }
    function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        address payable winner;
        uint index=random()% players.length;
        winner=payable(players[index]);
        winner.transfer(getBalance());
       players=new address[](0);
    }
    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender==manager);
        _;
    }
    function getPlayers() public view returns(address[] memory){
        return players;
    }}
```

> lottery test file

```js
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const Lottery = artifacts.require('Lottery');
contract('Lottery', (accounts) => {
  let lottery;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    lottery = await Lottery.new({ from: accounts[0] });
  });

  describe('Lottery Contract', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {
      assert.ok(lottery.address);
    });
    it('allows one acc to enter', async () => {
      await lottery.enter({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether'),
      });
      const players = await lottery.getPlayers({ from: accounts[0] });

      assert.equal(accounts[0], players[0]);
      assert.equal(1, players.length);
    });
    it('allows multiple acc to enter', async () => {
      await lottery.enter({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether'),
      });
      await lottery.enter({
        from: accounts[1],
        value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether'),
      });
      await lottery.enter({
        from: accounts[2],
        value: web3.utils.toWei('0.02', 'ether'),
      });
      const players = await lottery.getPlayers({ from: accounts[0] });

      assert.equal(accounts[0], players[0]);
      assert.equal(accounts[1], players[1]);
      assert.equal(accounts[2], players[2]);
      assert.equal(3, players.length);
    });
    it('requires a min amount of ether to enter', async () => {
      try {
        await lottery.enter({
          from: accounts[0],
          value: 0,
        });
        assert(false);
      } catch (err) {
        assert(err);
      }
    });

    it('only manager can call pickWinner', async () => {
      try {
        await lottery.pickWinner({
          from: accounts[1],
        });
        assert(false);
      } catch (err) {
        assert(err);
      }
    });
    it('sends money to the winner and resets the players', async () => {
      await lottery.enter({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: web3.utils.toWei('2', 'ether'),
      });
      const initialBal = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
      await lottery.pickWinner({
        from: accounts[0],
      });
      const finalBal = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]);
      const difference = finalBal - initialBal;
      console.log(difference);
      assert(difference > web3.utils.toWei('1.8', 'ether'));
    });
  });
});
```

I am having this error, please tell me how to do the conversion. It shows the last test is not passing, please help I am a beginner.
[image: error]

Comment: what do you get if you console.log(initialBal) and console.log(finalBalance)

Comment: initialBal =0 , finalBal=0

Comment: check if you have enough balance to send 2 ethers?

Comment: please tell how do i find out

Comment: Zoha, you are using accounts, but where they came from?. can you console.log(accounts)

Comment: Yes i can see accounts through console.log(accounts) but when i console the balance of accounts[0], i get 0

Comment: Can you paste your truffle.config.js. setting

Comment: https://github.com/ZohaAkram/SContractprac2/blob/main/truffle-config.js

Comment: this is the github link to my truffle.config.js file

Comment: do u have ganache gui installed

Comment: yes I have ganache

Answer (score 1):

Your truffle.config.js has no connection to ganache.

add this to your truffle-config.js

```
networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", 
      // default ganache gui listens to 7545
      port: 7545, 
      network_id: "*", 
    },
```

Make sure your ganache is running and run the test.

Comment: Yes I just checked this, but the error was due to the conversion of the getBalance() value, it returned string value therefore the test was failing. Thanks btw!!

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner too, but i guess you should use web3.utils.BN when receiving balances. More info here: [about BN in Web3.js docs.](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#bn)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you help me with syntax please? Like I have written web3. eth. getBalance(acc[0]). So should i store it in a variable and then convert it?

Comment: I guess i got it. web3.eth.getBalance() returns string so when you try to get a difference it fails. You could do it like const initialBal = web3.utils.toBN(await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]))

Comment: i am having initial balance = 0

Answer (score 0):

It might have been the case regarding string, but when I tried and was getting the same error, it was because my 'difference' was a number that was not greater than output of 'web3.utils.toWei("1.8", "ether")', and since 'difference' should have been greater, assert was throwing an error.

Comment: Not an issue with string being the return type, it is because of the difference being a smaller number than the expected number in wei.
In Wei we would get 1.8 e+18,
while the difference itself would be a number of (some_number)e +17

Comment: So, there should be a section in code, where you are trying to send ether to the winner but the expected is not happening and therefore the difference we get is not a number that is of equal size.